# Android widget not working while offline deployment

Tags: android, android-studio, widget, android-volley

I have an android app widget that retrieves some JSON response from an API. It uses **volley** for HTTP requests and also has a tap to update option. It works fine if the user is online while adding the widget. Then it successfully retrieves the information from the API. But if the user is offline while adding the widget it does not get updated. Even after the user comes to online after widget deployment and "tap to update" the widget, it does not get updated. How do I make it works so that the user can deploy offline and after coming online, by tapping to update, it will get updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably setting the `setOnClickPendingIntent` for update operation after the network Volley call (which does not finish and the pendingIntent is never set).
Try to add `onClickPendingIntent` in Volley call error/failure block and call `updateAppWidget()` from there as well.